# puzzle in derivation of entropy of sum

Tags: probability, entropy

I was reading through a derivation of an entropy of a sum example, and cannot understand one step.

The statement to be proven is if $Z=X+Y$ then $H(Z|X) = H(Y|X)$, where H() is discrete Shannon entropy.

The derivation:
$Z = X+Y$, Hence note $p(Z=z|X=x) = p(Y=z-x|X=x)$.

\begin{align}
H(Z|X) &= \sum p(x) H(Z|X=x)
\\
 &= -\sum_x p(x) \sum_z p(Z=z|X=x) \log p(Z=z|X=x)
\\
 &= -\sum_x p(x) \sum_y p(Y=z-x|X=x) \log p(Y=z-x|X=x)
\\
 &= \sum p(x) H(Y|X=x)
\\
 &= H(Y|X)
\end{align}

My issue is the step introducing probability $p(Y=z-x|X=x)$.

First, I think this probability is always $1$,
because $Y$ is *defined* to be $z-x$, so how can it be anything else?

Second, an expression $\sum_y p(Y=z-x)$ bothers, because in summing over the index $y$, $y$ is supposed to be an independent thing, but here $Y$ depends on $x$ through $Y=z-x$.  Actually the notation in the derivation does not clarify $y$ verus $Y$ also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation convention here is that the capitalized letter denotes a random variable, and the lower-case letter denotes a *possible value* for the corresponding random variable. For example if $X$ and $Y$ are the respective results of two rolls of a die, then $x$ would be any one of $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$. Similarly $y$ stands for any one of those same six values.

In your derivation, for a given $x$ the quantity $P(Y=z-x\mid X=x)$ is not always $1$, since $Y$ and $X$ (and $Z$) are random variables and can take a variety of values. Try plugging values like $x=3, z=8$ in the die-rolling example.  If you know that $X=3$, the conditional probability is not $1$ that $Y=8-3$.

For your second question, the expression $\sum_y p(Y=z-x\mid X=x)$ has a typographical error. It should be $\sum_z p(Y=z-x\mid X=x)$. To get the next line you realize that for a given $x$, summing over all possible values of $z$ is the same as summing over all possible values of $y$, so the inner sum is  just $H(Y\mid X=x)$.

Comment: And I think I understand the second. To restate, you are saying that, although with x fixed, Y and z differ by an offset, in evaluating the all possible probabilities (1-6 for the dice), Y must take on the 1-6 range, or z takes on the range 1-x .. 6-x, so the sum is equivalent, just with different start end points.

Comment: I briefly thought I understood the first point, but decided no.

Z is _defined_ to be X+Y, so all the randomness in Z is due to X,Y. It does not add any extra randomness.

Thus if Z is known, and X is known, Y can be exactly determined as Z-X. 

If this is correct, I guess the clue is that z is different from Z?  z is taking on all values during the sum, which in turn forces Y to take on its range of values, all conditioned on X=x.  

Does this sound like I understand?

Comment: @isolatedstudent Yes, your understanding is correct: $Z$ is different from $z$.